# how do i install latex style files on os x?

Tags: macos, latex

I've been trying to install some latex style files on my mac machine. However, I am confused with how. I put them in /usr/local/texlive/2013/textmf-dist/
And, when I try to update them by typing texhash or mktexlsr in the terminal, I got the following message:

```
wireless-10-146-48-120:~ jungsookim$ texhash
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
wireless-10-146-48-120:~ jungsookim$ mktexlsr
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
mktexlsr: Done.
wireless-10-146-48-120:~ jungsookim$
```

What's wrong with this?

I successfully installed them on my previous mac machine and my windows machine; but, for some reason, I have been struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

As the `texhash` and `mktexlsr` need to write to system files within the /usr/local directory, you will need to run the commands with sudo (i.e. `sudo texhash` and `sudo mktexlsr`) This will prompt for your password, and will then run the programs with administrator privlidges.

Comment: `sudo texhash` gives error: sudo: texhash: command not found